# jquery mouseenter returns boolean

Tags: jquery, hover

I read in the jquery API Ref, that mouseenter and mouseleave return jQuery object. But they actually return boolean. So the hover in jquery 1.9.0 doesnt really works, as the code is:

```
return this.mouseenter( fnOver ).mouseleave( fnOut || fnOver );
```

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: How did you guess from that line that *it doesn't work*?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object true has no method 'mouseleave'

Comment: Show us your jQuery code calling `.hover()`

Comment: TraditionalTabs = function() {
        this.children("li").each(function() {
            $(this).hover(function() {
                $(".hover", 
                this).stop().animate({opacity: 0.9}, 700, "easeOutSine")
            }, function() {
                $(".hover", this).stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 700, "easeOutExpo")
            })
        })
    };

Comment: Please edit your question and add all relevant code

Comment: The code that calls this doesn't really matter. My question is: is it expected, that mouseenter() should return Boolean instead of jQuery object? And if so - why in the API Ref is stated that it returns jQuery object?

Comment: Your code is important because I'm afraid it is only happening to you.  For instance, [this works](http://jsfiddle.net/rBRmk/). Anyways, `.mouseenter()` doesn't return a Boolean. This could be a real bug or not; But, the only way to discern it is by looking at your jQuery API usage. It's your choice

Comment: Anyways, thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set an event handler like that. You should give it a try like this:

```
return this.mouseenter( fnOver ).mouseleave( fnOut() || fnOver() );
```

The example you've provived is same like:

```
alert( true || false );
alert( false || true );
```

Where in both examples the output will be `true` because it's a boolean truth.

However, you can try creating a unique handler which will in it's structure contain the logic of both `fnOut` and `fnOver` functions.

Comment: That line code is from jQuery 1.9 codebase. I'm afraid your answer is out of context

Comment: aha, so @user1109783 post your code, paste it on urloment.com or on jsfiddle.net

Comment: But again - this is not my code. This is deep into to the included js files.

Comment: is TraditionalTabs yours or a jQuery plugin?

Comment: it has a rather confusing jQuery logic... why don't you write a plugin yourself?

Comment: nothing is irrelevant. why don't you use tabs from Twitter's Bootstrap?

Comment: Because I am upgrading jquery version in existing project.

Comment: why not stick to the project's current jquery version?

Comment: How is this relevant? We have our reasons and this is not the time to discuss them.

Comment: everything is relative, thus everything is irrelevantly relevant, and relevantly irrelevant! if it works, why spoil it?

Answer (score 0):

Found out why this happens. One of the frameworks was overriding on() function.